# Get the value of active li in ul

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the active li from a ul in jqvalue but all i am getting is null. I've also tried to write the value of the ul using console dir (to try and simulate php's `var_dump` but nothing is happening there either

Here is my jfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=MDbkUMciB7

Here is the code

```
function monthly_payment(){
    var interest = $('ul.credit').find('li.active').data('interest');
    console.dir($('ul.credit'));
alert(interest);
      // var iinterest   = interest_rate / 1200;


}


<ul id="credit">
<li interest = "0.056" class="active"><a href="#"><span id="excellent" class="0.056">excellent</span></a></li>
<li interest = "0.099"><a href="#"><span id="good" class="0.099">good</span></a></li>                       <li interest = "0.169"a href="#"><span id="fair" class="0.169">fair</span></a></li>
<li interest = 0.299><a href="#"><span id="bad" class="0.299">bad</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The attribute should be `data-interest`, not `interest`. You'll still access it with `.data('interest')`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change class to ID i.e `li.credit` to `li#credit` and `interest` to `data-interest`

**HTML**

```
<ul id="credit" name="credit">
            <li data-interest = "0.056" class="active"><a href="#"><span id="excellent" class="0.056">excellent</span></a></li>
            <li data-interest = "0.099"><a href="#"><span id="good" class="0.099">good</span></a></li>                      
           <li data-interest = "0.169"><a href="#"><span id="fair" class="0.169">fair</span></a></li>
            <li data-interest = 0.299><a href="#"><span id="bad" class="0.299">bad</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    monthly_payment();
 });


function monthly_payment(){
    var interest = $('ul#credit').find('li.active').data('interest');
    alert(interest);
   console.dir($('ul.credit'));
       var iinterest   = interest_rate / 1200;
       payment = principal * interest / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + interest), monthly_period)));
       payment = Math.round(payment * 100) / 100;
       return payment;

}
```

Comment: are you the persb that helped me on jfiddle

Comment: Name is not a valid attribute of a UL. `console.dir($('ul.credit'));` will no longer work if credit is an ID. `return payment;` would likely look better if you returned `payment.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use data attributes, then prefix it with `data-`

Your HTML should be:

```
<ul id="credit">
<li data-interest = "0.056" class="active"><a href="#"><span id="excellent" class="0.056">excellent</span></a></li>
<li data-interest = "0.099"><a href="#"><span id="good" class="0.099">good</span></a></li>                       <li data-interest = "0.169"a href="#"><span id="fair" class="0.169">fair</span></a></li>
<li data-interest = 0.299><a href="#"><span id="bad" class="0.299">bad</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And, as mplungjan, said, class names cannot be started with numbers. It has to start with alphabet.

```
.1{
 /* bad */
}

.some1{
 /* good */
}
```

Comment: and not have a class name starting with a digit

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
var interest = $('ul#credit').find('li.active').attr('interest');
```

you have 'credit' as id in your html.

Comment: No. data- should be prefixed