# Finding selected option in mdl-select

Tags: javascript, material-design

Let us take the example below. Suppose I want to find the name of the country selected using javascript. How do I do it ?

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fullwidth">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1" value="Belarus" readonly tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="sample1" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
    <ul for="sample1" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Germany</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Belarus</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Russia</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: same problem is already answered here in thread.
Click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891226/get-the-value-of-active-li-in-ul

Comment: but i need a way to find out the currently selected `li` item. Should i assign an onClick to each one ?

Comment: sorry, i can get the data-value directly from the input field, didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add a onclick event on every li elements and fire a callback function to show the result..